# Security considerations behind this code snippet in C

Tags: c, security, static-analysis

I found this code on git and wanted to use it, but someone made a comment about a security bug in it. I don't seem to identify it:

```
int32_t read_arrbuff(FILE *f, uint32_t *arrmap) {
  int32_t i = 0, n_map;
  fread(&n_map, sizeof(n_map), 1, f);
  if (n_map > 256)
    return -1;
  while (n_map--) {
    fread(&arrmap[i++], sizeof(uint32_t), 1, f);
  }
  return n_map;
}
```

Comment: Suppose the first int read has a negative value... What do you think the function does?

Comment: Or if `arrmap` is smaller than the amount of bytes you want to read.

Comment: This is a weird way to write such a function anyway to be honest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken in isolation, the problems include:

- You don't check that `f` is not NULL.
- You don't check that `arrmap` is not NULL.
- You don't check that the first `fread()` was successful.
- You don't fully validate the value that is read; negative or zero values will throw things off badly.
- You don't check that the second `fread()` was successful.
- You always return `-1`, regardless of whether anything worked or failed.

Which of those are security problems?  At some levels, all of them.  In some contexts, you could assume that `f` and `arrmap` are legitimate without checking.  Not checking that the reads are successful, especially the first, is a serious problem. The negative values for `n_map` would be a serious issue.  Claiming success when every read failed would be a problem.

When the loop completes, `n_map` is set to `-1` (it was zero before the post-decrement).  So, you return -1 on failure or success.  That's not helpful.  It should almost certainly return the value of `n_map` that was read from file, so the caller can tell how many values are in the array.

It is usually best not to hard code a size limit like `256` into the program.  The interface should include the array size and you should check against the passed array size.

Working to the original interface, you could use:

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

extern int32_t read_arrbuff(FILE *f, uint32_t *arrmap);

int32_t read_arrbuff(FILE *f, uint32_t *arrmap)
{
    int32_t n_map;
    if (fread(&n_map, sizeof(n_map), 1, f) != 1)
        err_syserr("failed to read data (count)\n");
    if (n_map > 256 || n_map <= 0)
        return -1;
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < n_map; i++)
    {
        if (fread(&arrmap[i], sizeof(uint32_t), 1, f) != 1)
            err_syserr("failed to read data (value %" PRId32 ")\n", i);
    }
    return n_map;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc != 1)
        err_usage("");

    char file[] = "data";

    /* Create data file */
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "wb");
    if (fp == NULL)
        err_syserr("failed to open file '%s' for writing\n", file);
    int32_t nmap = 32;
    if (fwrite(&nmap, sizeof(nmap), 1, fp) != 1)
        err_syserr("failed to write to file '%s'\n", file);
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < nmap; i++)
    {
        if (fwrite(&i, sizeof(i), 1, fp) != 1)
            err_syserr("failed to write to file '%s'\n", file);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    /* Read data file */
    fp = fopen(file, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
        err_syserr("failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", file);

    uint32_t amap[256];
    int32_t rc = read_arrbuff(fp, amap);
    printf("rc = %" PRId32 "\n", rc);

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < rc; i++)
        printf("%3" PRId32 " = %3" PRId32 "\n", i, amap[i]);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

You can debate whether the unilateral exits imposed by `err_syserr()` are appropriate.   (The declarations and source for the `err_*()` functions is in `stderr.h` and `stderr.c`, and is available from [GitHub](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq).)

An alternative version taking the maximum array size from a function parameter is:

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

extern int32_t read_arrbuff(FILE *f, int32_t a_size, uint32_t arrmap[a_size]);

int32_t read_arrbuff(FILE *f, int32_t a_size, uint32_t arrmap[a_size])
{
    int32_t n_map;
    assert(f != NULL && arrmap != NULL && a_size > 0 && a_size <= 256);
    if (fread(&n_map, sizeof(n_map), 1, f) != 1)
    {
        err_sysrem("failed to read data (count)\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (n_map > a_size || n_map <= 0)
    {
        err_sysrem("count %" PRId32 " is out of range 1..%" PRId32 "\n",
                   n_map, a_size);
        return -1;
    }
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < n_map; i++)
    {
        if (fread(&arrmap[i], sizeof(uint32_t), 1, f) != 1)
        {
            err_syserr("failed to read data (value %" PRId32 " of %" PRId32 ")\n",
                       i, n_map);
        }
    }
    return n_map;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc != 1)
        err_usage("");

    char file[] = "data";

    /* Create data file */
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "wb");
    if (fp == NULL)
        err_syserr("failed to open file '%s' for writing\n", file);
    int32_t nmap = 32;
    if (fwrite(&nmap, sizeof(nmap), 1, fp) != 1)
        err_syserr("failed to write to file '%s'\n", file);
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < nmap; i++)
    {
        if (fwrite(&i, sizeof(i), 1, fp) != 1)
            err_syserr("failed to write to file '%s'\n", file);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    /* Read data file */
    fp = fopen(file, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
        err_syserr("failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", file);

    enum { AMAP_SIZE = 256 };
    uint32_t amap[AMAP_SIZE];
    int32_t rc = read_arrbuff(fp, AMAP_SIZE, amap);
    printf("rc = %" PRId32 "\n", rc);

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < rc; i++)
        printf("%3" PRId32 " = %3" PRId32 "\n", i, amap[i]);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

This version reports a specific error and returns on error. It makes semi-appropriate assertions on entry (the 256 limit is not necessarily appropriate, but is consistent with the original code).

The output is unexciting (and the same from both):

```
rc = 32
  0 =   0
  1 =   1
  2 =   2
  3 =   3
  4 =   4
  5 =   5
  6 =   6
  7 =   7
  8 =   8
  9 =   9
 10 =  10
 11 =  11
 12 =  12
 13 =  13
 14 =  14
 15 =  15
 16 =  16
 17 =  17
 18 =  18
 19 =  19
 20 =  20
 21 =  21
 22 =  22
 23 =  23
 24 =  24
 25 =  25
 26 =  26
 27 =  27
 28 =  28
 29 =  29
 30 =  30
 31 =  31
```

Comment: This is very impressive, thanks a lot, now I understand all the issues.